# Get Google to Index Dynamic PHP Pages

Tags: url, indexing, sitemap

I'm planning on having a website where the links aren't set HTML pages (ex. mypage.com/contact_me.html) but dynamic (profile.php?uid=32320&mode=2).

How can I get Google to index a website like this, so that every profile (much like facebook has done) is indexed separately on google?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think those URIs are not beeing indexed by Google?

Comment: Just make sure there are links to those pages, then Google will index them. A combination of a html- and xml-sitemap would be fine.

Answer (score 5):

Google finds dynamic pages like that just fine (assuming it can find them via links).

You can always provide an [XML sitemap](http://www.sitemaps.org/) if you're paranoid.

Answer (score 2):

google has a [site to help webmasters](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) get their pages indexed better as well as some [analytics facilities](http://www.google.com/analytics/) you might find of value also

Answer (score 0):

Use [URL-rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to make the pages more meaningful to search engines. There are limits as to the number and depths of dynamic URLs with querystrings that Google will follow (but it will follow some).

Comment: Do you have a reference for your last statement about the limit?